# A short expression to pick from two values based on bool?

Tags: python

If one has two values in a list:

```
choices = [1,2]
```

and one wants to assign these values to two variables based on a `bool` parameter (let's call it `ascending`) like this:

```
if ascending:
  a,b = choices[1], choices[0]
else:
  a,b = choices[0], choices[1]
```

one can express this in one line like this:

```
a,b  = choices[ascending], choices[not ascending]
```

or

```
a,b = choices[::(-1)**ascending]
```

I like the last one better, but it's probably not extremely transparent. What are other  concise but more readable ways to do the same?

Comment: Does `choices` always contain ordered 2 values from start?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest no

Comment: so how can you directly access the indices if the values are in unknown order?

Comment: Do you still need `choices` afterwards?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest In the situation where I came across this, they are in fact different and ordered. Hence the name `ascending` which may be confusing. Here we just want to pick the reversed values from `choices` if `ascending`, the original if not, without assuming anything about the content of choices.

Answer (score 2):

If the original values are always in ascending order, perhaps this would be more expressive of your intent:

```
a,b = sorted(choices, reverse=ascending)
```

Otherwise simpler is generally better (see Kelly's answer) but I could think of ways to make it even more obscure:

For example:

```
a,b = (iter,reversed)[ascending](choices)
```

Alternatively, if one option is more likely than the other you could do the assignment based on that one and swap the variables if it's the other case:

```
a,b = choices
if ascending: a,b = b,a
```

Answer (score 1):

Some ways...

```
b,a = choices[::ascending or -1]
a,b = choices[::-ascending or 1]
a,b = choices[::-1] if ascending else choices
a,b = choices.pop(ascending), *choices
```

The last one modifies the list.

Or with multiple lines but kinda clean and I suspect fastest:

```
if ascending:
  b,a = choices
else:
  a,b = choices
```

Benchmarks (times in nanoseconds):

```
 asc = False    asc = True
------------   ------------
 30.2 ±  0.3    30.2 ±  0.3   if ascending:
                                b,a = choices
                              else:
                                a,b = choices
 60.2 ±  1.3    60.8 ±  2.1   a,b = choices[ascending], choices[not ascending]
 62.8 ±  0.6    63.5 ±  0.9   if ascending:
                                a,b = choices[1], choices[0]
                              else:
                                a,b = choices[0], choices[1]
 30.3 ±  0.3   125.0 ±  3.7   a,b = choices[::-1] if ascending else choices
 30.1 ±  0.1   178.2 ±  4.5   a,b = reversed(choices) if ascending else choices
124.5 ±  3.5   126.1 ±  5.8   b,a = choices[::ascending or -1]
133.6 ±  7.0   123.8 ±  2.6   a,b = choices[::-1 if ascending else 1]
143.4 ±  6.4   139.9 ±  6.1   a,b = choices[::-ascending or 1]
169.4 ± 18.5   441.2 ± 20.4   a,b = choices[::(-1)**ascending]
```

Code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVS9ktMwEK5o_BQ7RyHJOCEGMgNm0lJS0fk8N44i3wli2SMpN9xk8iQ018DQ8go8Bk_D6ieO8wM0NLa0u_r2291P-vKtf7B3nXp8_LqxzeT1ryffG921YGUrpAXZ9p22cZd4j7G1lcZKbvbeVtQqQ_tK3CcJ71bCwAIIIUkiG6gNF2ol1W2RANTZEl38rpNcmDKvsmE9qxKxNuI8aDYKyqskOfYO6KMo1dlD1rMTRUEnOUvTccQyq48iBh90GibnWYtiksO4NnDcwQWeVnwEfbnEC-hHBC7nry4QOAHU4l5oI1Y02tnfjuC8psZq2VM2Nf1aWkqu1bUiDEcaYhCxJE3XkQzIstakShpkd8CTCt7ViJnBB73xZfZaKksbsh2CFjsEBHAHnVDcGS8YF41twRSO-PtOCW8QnwWnLoD5bcCrM1iyAR35OXU6dlteAC1RCWXFQooBf5esROOlayhnLlsTqFqkikepx6dOydQaFtXsliGzQ7PGwflkJa9OzGVp01y8CRZnMHgzsPWIUBbzqnLxDkoLu9EqZEdtwzPPwKt8xCjxrb1xOLpWt4K-mAfS_2g4gEH8Hgtqrv40tbdwGAc6d1dDJfxkHABq0y6Fxqh8lqbzaLS4Dw8C5VlImMXIRfgxeB4N-yOxaaP7Oq37HpfU4gDDJAk6EdqX5NXgt6401MzAL_bV08zgk3hY-Kn69txkJ2PdDxx9T6NeyLaYT_NmBz9_wLZ45ZcAl4xkiknb2tI0gqYOFbVB0PWxk4ryeFMYO-jxP-Dz4SJq0a9rLtxVdPPDLwoG06cvZ4yFBzu-2_v3-zc)):

```py
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev

codes = '''

if ascending:
  a,b = choices[1], choices[0]
else:
  a,b = choices[0], choices[1]

a,b = choices[ascending], choices[not ascending]

a,b = choices[::(-1)**ascending]

b,a = choices[::ascending or -1]

a,b = choices[::-1 if ascending else 1]

if ascending:
  b,a = choices
else:
  a,b = choices

a,b = choices[::-ascending or 1]

a,b = choices[::-1] if ascending else choices

a,b = reversed(choices) if ascending else choices

'''.strip().split('\n\n')

choices = ['foo', 'bar']
for ascending in False, True:
  print(f'{ascending=}')
  for code in codes:
    a = b = None
    exec(code)
    print(a, b)
  print()

times = {c: ([], []) for c in codes}
def stats(c):
  false, true = (
    (mean(ts), stdev(ts))
    for ts in times[c]
    for ts in [[t*1e9 for t in sorted(ts)[:5]]]
  )
  return false[0] + true[0], false, true

for _ in range(25):
  for ascending in False, True:
    setup = f"choices = ['foo', 'bar']; {ascending = }"
    for c in codes:
      number = 10**5
      t = timeit(c, setup, number=number) / number
      times[c][ascending].append(t)

print('asc = False    asc = True')
for c in sorted(codes, key=stats):
  _, false, true = stats(c)
  # print('{:5.1f} ± {:4.1f}   {:5.1f} ± {:4.1f}  '.format(*false, *true), ' '.join(c.split()))
  print('{:5.1f} ± {:4.1f}   {:5.1f} ± {:4.1f}  '.format(*false, *true), c.strip().replace('\n', '\n' + ' '*30))
```